# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed when sending queued mails

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
Log::info('Sending email', array(
    'title' => $attributes['title'],
    'recipient' => $attributes['email']
));

Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $attributes, function($message) use ($attributes)
{
    $message
        ->to($attributes['email'])
        ->subject($attributes['title']);
});
```

The problem's with the closure being passed to `Mail::queue`. What's wrong? This is exactly the same with what's [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#queueing-mail).

Comment: What's in your `$attributes` variable? Does it contain a `Paginator` object? Can you `var_dump` it for us?

Comment: Is that the exact error? 'Serialization of 'Closure' not allowed'?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I **assume** that `$attributes` is something that you're trying to pass to e-mail view `welcome`. IF it is, so you'll need to put it in a array. In that case, should be something loike that:

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', array('attributes' => $attributes), function($message) use ($attributes)
{
    $message
        ->to($attributes['email'])
        ->subject($attributes['title']);
});
```

... this may work for you! :D

Comment: And how do I access to these attributes now ?

Comment: @Fractaliste ... as it was an array, that in fact it is! :D

Comment: The `'attributes'` key become var name inside the view. Let say, for the sake of the argument, that I have this `array('atrr' = > $attributes);`, then I'd have to call them, inside the view, that way `$atrr['email']`. Got it?

Comment: Okay the key become a var name. I thought that `$data = array('attr' => 'anything')` should be accessed in the view with `$data['attr']`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error message. My problem was my $attributes was an Eloquent model, which I guess isn't serializable. I had to change:

`Mail::queue('emails.welcome', array('attributes' => $attributes), function($message) use ($attributes)`

to

`$attrArray = $attributes->toArray();
Mail::queue('emails.welcome', array('attributes' => $attributes), function($message) use ($attrArray)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I recently got this error aswell. And the cause was putting a $request instance inside the mail queue callback.

```
Mail::queue('emails.welcome',$data,function(){

$email = $request->input('email'); // <- apparently this will cause a closure error


});
```

I also learned from searching that you can't put unserializable data inside closures. That includes eloquent models or objects.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is using $this inside of the closure. Check out the file SerializableClosures.php and function serialize(). 
$this->to and $this->subject are references to fields on the Class and not in the Closure so to fix the code you have to make them local variables and pass them to the closure.